# How to Silence the Notification when pressing volume button?

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm creating a notification that fires at specific time using Alarm Manager, it works but it doesn't stop playing when pressing volume buttons like when a phone call comes in

Here's how i create a notification

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);

        notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
        notification.setTicker("This's the ticker");//status bar text
        notification.setContentTitle("title");
        notification.setContentText("text");

        notification.setPriority(1);

        Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifysound);
        notification.setSound(sound);

        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(ns);

        manager.notify(0,notification.build());
```

Hope some one will help me figure out  how to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not an android dev, so I can't assure this is the best solution, but couldn't you create an event listener which triggers when the volume key is pressed, adjusting the volume from the listener?

Comment: I've tried using a listener, but it didn't work. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First, build the notification to use the system *alarm* audio stream rather than the default (ring) audio stream.

--- Your notification code

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifysound);
NotificationCompat builder = NotificationCompat.builder(this)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
        .setSound(sound, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setTicker("This's the ticker")
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("text");
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

[Perhaps setting the notification priority and category like this will also make your app's alarms mute during a phone call. Look into the `AudioManager`.]

Then configure the volume controls to adjust the alarm volume while in your Activity.

--- MainActivity.java

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
```

Within this Activity, the volume controls will now adjust the alarm volume, and that will control your notification alarms.